# Display including Zero using SQL count(*) and group by

Tags: sql

For this query  i want to display records zero using SQL Count(*) and group by below is my SQL Query:

```
SELECT  B.BranchName as Filter,
Coalesce(COUNT(*), '0')   AS NoofSplits,
SUM(ls.Amount) AS TotalLoanValue
FROM    dbo.tblBranch B                     
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblLoan L ON L.BranchID = B.BranchID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblLoanSplit LS ON L.LoanID = LS.LoanID
WHERE  LS.DateSettlement BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY B.BranchName
ORDER BY B.BranchName
```

Comment: Do you get any error? If yes, please, indicate it.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Where is it meant to obtain the definitive list of branch names from? Or do you expect it to generate every possible string that fits within the data type for that column and list 0s for each of them? That'll generate a lot of noise.

Comment: `Coalesce` as in `Coalesce(COUNT(*), '0')` has no meaning since  `COUNT(*)` never returns `null`. Can you provide a small set of sample data that illustrates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `COUNT(*)` when you do an outer join, this will return 1 svn if there was no row to join. You must COUNT the join column of the Outer Table, in your case :

```
SELECT  B.BranchName as Filter,
    COUNT(LS.LoanID)   AS NoofSplits,
SUM(ls.Amount) AS TotalLoanValue
FROM    dbo.tblBranch B                     
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblLoan L ON L.BranchID = B.BranchID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblLoanSplit LS ON L.LoanID = LS.LoanID
WHERE  LS.DateSettlement BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY B.BranchName
ORDER BY B.BranchName
```